# how to communicate with daemonset pod from another pod in the same node?

Tags: kubernetes, daemonset

i want a daemonset-redis where every node will have it's own caching and each deployment pod will communicate with it's local daemonset-redis how to achieve it? how to reference daemonset pod in the same node from within docker-container?

**UPDATE**:
i rather not use service option and make sure each pod access its local daemonset

```py
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: redislocal
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: redislocal
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: redislocal
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: redislocal
        image: redis:5.0.5-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          hostPort: 6379
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a way of **not** using a `service`.

You can [Expose Pod Information to Containers Through Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/).

And you can use `status.hostIP` to know the ip address of node where `pod` is running.
This was introduced in Kubernetes 1.7 [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/42717)

You can add that to your `pod` or `deployment` yaml:

```
env:
- name: HOST_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

It will set an variable `HOST_IP` which will have a value of node ip on which the `pod` is running, then you can use it to connect to a local `DeamonSet`.

Answer (score 1):

you should define a service ( selecting all redis pods ) and then communicate with redis from other pods

Comment: I also think this is the solution, but will pods strictly communicate with the local deamon? Do services provide that guarantee?

Comment: i rather not use a service. i think theres another way i hoped to get that answer with accessing the node on which the pods are running with some kind of alias